# Framework to create a community in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I received an assignment to develop a community to a club with about 1,000 members. Members shall be able to keep in touch, post pictures/movies and read about/register for events the club arranged.

I am looking to develop this in ASP.NET as it is what I know best (is it a wise choice?). I wonder if you could recommend any FREE framework or guide I can start from when I create the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use:

1. DotNetNuke, Umbraco, MojoPortal or the likes - most of the code is already written, but creating new modules/features is not that easy/simple.
2. n2cms, Project Orchard - were made just to be especially to extend, although they have less built-ins.

Answer (score 3):

There is an ASP.NET project based on BlogEngine.NET, YAF, ScrewTurn wiki - which may be useful although I do not think there's any OOTB support for events: http://sueetie.com

Answer (score 1):

Check out Microsoft's [Club Site Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/club)

> A starting point for creating a web site for your club or organization. Includes a news > posting, calendaring, member directory, and photo album systems.
>
> Create news announcements and news
>   articles with photos or links to a
>   photo album. Create and view
>   Membership lists of club members.
>   Create photo albums and share the
>   photos from your club activities.
>
> - [Download the Club Web Site Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc533487.aspx)
> - [Download Generic Scripts for SQL Server 2000 & MSDE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0DD83A11-6980-4951-A192-DA6EACC6A19E&displaylang=en)
> - [Download the Event Calendar Control](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/club/EventCalendar.zip)
> - [View Discussion Forum](http://forums.asp.net/1004/ShowForum.aspx)

Would that be something you could use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use open source [DotnetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) Content Management System